# what will be the official name of c++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11

as I know standard should be accepted this year. So, will it be c++11?

Comment: Perhaps hex to keep the 0? `c++0b`

Comment: I don't understand the down voting.

Comment: @ Eugen Constantin Dinca: Not really. It is often convenient to refer to the various standards by their adoption year when talking about older compilers. For example, Bjarne Stroustrup himself call the old standard C++98, so it is very likely that the community will adopt the term "C++11" as a convenient way of saying "The C++ standard that was released in 2011." edit - Although C++0b is too cute to deny.

Comment: I dont think this question needs to be closed for the stated reason, "Not a real question."  It is a real question.  Maybe off topic, but the closers should have reffered the OP to programmers.stackexchange.com instead of just lowering the close-hammer.

Comment: The official name has always been and will continue to be C++.  C++98, C++03, C++0x, and C++11 (or C++12) are commonly understood unofficial names (for things with official names like ISO/IEC 14882:2003).

Comment: "cannot be reasonably answered" - actually there's the perfect answer I've accepted

Comment: @Juhn Dibling:  Why do you think this question would be acceptable on programmers.se?  This is an objective question, not about programmers, and doesn't belong there.  P.SE isn't just a dumping ground for questions that don't belong on SO.

Comment: @David:  Fair enough.  Then where does it belong?  It seems to me like a valid question.

Comment: @Boatzart: as soon as the last C++0x draft gets accepted it will become The C++ Standard. If you want to discuss it in the context of past standards or future drafts use C++0b or C++0c.

Comment: @John, @David et al.: I'd say it belongs just fine here. It's a sensible question (who doesn't want to know something as basic as "how am I supposed to refer to my programming language to avoid confusion?" Especially in the case of C++0x, whose "name" has already caused a lot of confusion on SO. Seems fitting that the question gets answered once and for all.

Comment: "standard should be accepted this year." It won't "should be" anything. It is _already_ an ISO standard. It has been approved and _published_. You can purchase it (at exorbitantly high prices) from the ISO website right now.

Comment: @NicolBolas: have you looked at the date of the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ED:  Since this question was asked the C++ Standard has been published.  In my answer I have changed past tense to present tense and elaborated a bit on things that have clarified since release.]

The name of the language according to the Standard is C++.  In order to distinguish it from other versions of the Standard it sometimes referred to as C++11, but that's not its official name.  Previous releases are often referred to as C++03 or C++98, but in converstions on StackOverflow "C++" by itself generally means the *current* version of C++, whatever that happens to be.

C++0x was just a placeholder identifier used to refer to the pre-release version of the Standard before it was published in order to distinguish it from other versions.  Today we have a new version being discussed by the committie; that version is currently being referred to as C++1y.

Regarding the 0x part, this is what [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html) has to say:

> The new standard is likely to be called C++11, but even a minor bureacratic delay could make that C++12. Personally, I prefer plain C++ and to use a year marker only when I need to distinguish it from previous versions of C++, such as ARM C++, C++98 and C++03. For now, I bow to convention and still use C++0x for the next version. Think of 'x' as hexadecimal.

When posting on SO, it is often referred to as C++11.  There is some confusion about which version of the C++ Standard is referred to when only the C++ tag is used without any disambiguation (such as the C++11 or C++03 tags), but it is generally assumed that the C++ tag refers to the current release.  As of this writing, that's C++11.

Comment: True, but it'll probably be many years before it's just "C++" and we refer to the C++ we know now solely as C++03, just as we explicitly refer to C++98 as such.

Comment: @GMan: Pretty sure that is going to happen, well, as soon as the new Standard is accepted.

Comment: @James:  That's probably the "minor bureaucratic delay" BS was referring to.

Comment: @DeadMG: That depends very much on the context.  On stackoverflow and comp.lang.c++, maybe near instantly.  At my workplace though, I'm sure it will be at least a year before we're allowed to use any new language/library features, since we infrequently switch compiler versions.

Comment: @John: See James' answer. C++0x isn't a **colloquial** identifier; it's a **placeholder** identifier. C++ is a **colloquial** name meaning C++98, C++03 or C++0x in a manner similar to "C" being a **colloquial** name for either C89, C90 or C99. (p.s., you could be a *little* more patient...)

Comment: C++ is also the name of 14882:1998 and in this sense is ambiguous. Now, you could say that since 14882:1998 was withdrawn, and 14882:2003 explicitly states that 14882:1998 is canceled there is no ambiguity (assuming the coming one standard does the same), but then there's no question. Assuming certain things about the OP means he wanted the answer "C++11" or "C++12" or "it could be either, since...".

Comment: A second issue is that although the previous versions of 14882 are being withdrawn as new version are published, compiler manufacturers still implement them, and because of that they cannot be ignored saying "bu the current (and only) standard says that the name is just C++". However, you are technically correct that the question was about the **official** name, a point to which I didn't attribute the proper significance, and thus technically you are right. Unfortunately, by the time I tried to cancel the downvote the answer was already accepted. (But it doesn't really affect your reputation:)

Answer (score 3):

It has been approved!  The official publication will take some time, but should still be out well before the end of the year.  We can start calling it **C++11** now.

http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/

**Edit:** [Herb Sutter on 2011-10-10](http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/10/iso-c11-published/) announces that the new ISO standard has been published. The [ISO Press Release](http://www.iso.org/iso/pressrelease.htm?refid=Ref1472) has this to say:

> ISO/IEC 14882:2011 defines the programming language and specifies
>   requirements for implementation. Also known as C++11, this is the
>   first major revision of the standard since 1998.

Answer (score 2):

The last two standards were named `C++98` and `C++03`, so one would assume this one will be `"C++XX".replace("XX", YearAccepted)`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning C++98 and C++03.  -0 for not mentioning that C++03 was not a new version in the sense that C++0x will be, just a "bugfix".  -1 for attempting to use a dot operator on a string literal.

Comment: error C2228: left of '.replace' must have class/struct/union

Comment: @AshleysBrain, @aschepler: Sorry, fell back into Python for a second. I have since recovered. :)

Comment: The last standard (and its course correction) were C++.  The addition of the date is an often useful colloquialism, and will be more useful when the next version is official (I hope this year).

Comment: @aschpler: I'm pretty sure that's just a widely-circulated myth.